# N to N relationship modeling in azure-table

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, denormalization, nosql

I have a subscription relationship to model... A user may subscribe to N feeds and each feed has N subscribers... A user clicking "My feeds" will be a common scenario and a Feed looking up his subscribers a even more common scenario...

My question is: How should I store this graph in a azure table in order to obtain good query performance on both scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your scenario I'd like to have two tables, one for users and his/her feeds, the other for feeds and the users subscribed on. Something like below in JSON format:

User entity in users table

```
{
  Partition Key: User ID,
  Row Key: Guid.NewGuid(),
  ...
}
```

UserFeed entity in users table

```
{
  Partition Key: User ID,
  Row Key: Feed ID
  ...
}
```

Feed entity in feeds table

```
{
  Partition Key: Feed ID
  Row Key: Giud.NewGuid(),
  ...
}
```

FeedSubsciber entity in feeds table

```
{
  Partition Key: Feed ID,
  Row Key: User ID,
  ...
}
```

Comment: The only concern with the @Leonardo response is the transactional consistency. Given the fact that your are using 2 tables you are unable to update, insert or delete inside the same transaction.